# How to show images from an ip camera as a live video while also doing some audio processing in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

In this application, I am using two audio devices, each of which can be used both as input and output devices. One audio device is used as an input and the other audio device uses the fed input sound as an output and same happens the other way around. While this audio processing goes on, I also try to show the image from an ip camera and update it to produce a live video.

A screenshot of the application:

[image]

As you can see, I can show the image, but not while doing any sort of audio processing. The problem is that whenever I try to do audio processing and show the video simultaneously, I run into problems as the program stops working altogether.

The slots I have are these:

```
private slots:
    void on_startVideo_clicked();

    void on_stopVideo_clicked();

    void on_startInput1_clicked();

    void on_stopInput1_clicked();

    void on_startInput2_clicked();

    void on_stopInput2_clicked();

    void readMoreInput1();

    void readMoreInput2();
```

Here all the slots, except `on_startVideo_clicked()` and `on_stopVideo_clicked()`, are relevant for audio processing and they work fine until I invoke the slots relevant for the video.

The slot for showing the video:

```
void MainWindow::on_startVideo_clicked()
{
    const std::string streamUrl = "http://operator:operator@axis-p5515/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=1920x1080&compression=0&dummy=param.mjpg";
    if (!capture.open(streamUrl))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "No input device availabe!");
    }
    else
    {
        videoState = true;
        ui->stopVideo->setEnabled(true);
        ui->startVideo->setEnabled(false);
        while(videoState){
            cv::Mat frame;
            capture >> frame;
            cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGBA);
            cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(ui->liveVideo->width(), ui->liveVideo->height()), 0, 0);
            QImage image(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
            ui->liveVideo->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
            QPixmap coloredImage(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
            QPainter painter(&coloredImage);
            painter.setOpacity(0.5);
            painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
            painter.drawRect(coloredImage.rect());
            ui->overlayVideo->setPixmap(coloredImage);
            qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using `OpenCV` for capturing the image and showing it. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Could you please point out where I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that could easily be solved with the [C++ standard thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/) library. Try running the audio processing and OpenCV stuff in different concurrently-executing threads.

Comment: As a side note, I would also recommend researching about getting different threads to run on different CPU cores, just to help speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with Mason Watmough's sentiment, you are using Qt and QThread abstracts a lot of the nasty stuff away and allows you to continue using signals and slots across the threads.

There is a good example on the [QThread class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) page which i've added at the bottom of this post (to keep the top cleaner)

The layout of your program will then look something like this:

```
- ControllerClass
- VideoController
- VideoWorker
- AudioController
- AudioWorker
```

You can then use your `ControllerClass` to spawn off the threads, connect up to signals and slots, then use the outputs from the two concurrently running threads to do whatever behaviour you want.

You would do this in a way similar to this:

```
myThread = new VideoController();
connect(myThread, SIGNAL(depthValues(float, float, float)), this, SLOT(on_depth_values(float, float, float)));
```

---

QThread Example:

```
    class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;

public slots:
    void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
        // ...
        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(operate(QString)), worker, SLOT(doWork(QString)));
        connect(worker, SIGNAL(resultReady(QString)), this, SLOT(handleResults(QString)));
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &);
signals:
    void operate(const QString &);
};
```